# how to create schedule for push notification in nodejs

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I need a help to create schedule for send a message from  node.js application server.
 i am new to this problem so can anybody please help me how can solve this?
i tried "node-schedule" module but it's not persist.

Comment: you can also use setTimeout with ease, if there are not too many notifications

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem yet @Loki Chandu?

Comment: i got it i'm using scheduler npm module with db

Comment: Definately, node-schedule is the best for node.js projects

Comment: @tareknoaman use below npm module for scheduling task and firebase for push notificatin.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Answer (score 4):

I may be late to answer this question but it might help others in the future.

in my case, I needed to send a notification on a specific date and time.

I used [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) which is a flexible cron-like and not-cron-like job scheduler for Node.js.

start with importing [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
```

then scheduling push notification as below

```
schedule.scheduleJob(
  `${pushNotification._id}`, //Job name, prefered to be unique 
  scheduledDate, // 2020-05-02T12:52:00.000Z
  async () => {
    await FCM.broadcast({
      topic: 'topic_name',
      title: 'sample title',
      body: 'sample body',
      imageUrl: 'image url sample',
    });
  }
);
```

and in case you want to cancel the job

```
schedule.cancelJob('job_id');
```

and in case you want to reschedule the job

```
schedule.rescheduleJob('job_id', 'scheduleDate');
```

hope this would help.

Comment: Hi, can the schedule date just be a date with a time? or do i have to add time as well? Also, in my app, when a user creates an order they are supposed to be reminded with the payment dates. Should i schedule a job when creating an order?